# font style is not working on domain

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I have two domains, one http://www.eu-ohne-mpu-fs.de/, second: http://eu-bw.de/. Second domain is the one where Wordpress Adress(URL) and Domain Adress(URL) is set. First one is pointing to the directory /eu-bw.de. In my child theme stylesheet i use Font-face CSS rule to style: title, headers and navigation fonts. That rule is working with second domain but not apply to number one. Also i use this code in function.php (the file is created in child theme directory) to enqueue parent theme stylesheet in to child theme style sheet:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_theme_root_uri() . '/eu-bw/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
?>
```

What should i change to have working fonts in both domains?

Comment: If you use the built in developer tools in your browser, the reason this happens is written in bright red in the error console

Comment: After research on the problem i have found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are any of the fonts in this style calling a font that is hosted on an online type tool like typekit or fonts.com? If so you may need to add the other URL to your recognized websites and relaunch your online typekit.

Comment: I use @font-face with generated fonts from my local libraries.